# java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: java, inputstream

I create a streamHelper function to load any file that is on the classpath, this is the path for my json file, but I got error when I using this function

```
streamHelper("/Users/my/IdeaProjects/rules-management/data_tacos-sample/post-migration/sourceData/config_-e48059402bd4.json")
```

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [/Users/my/IdeaProjects/rules-management/data_tacos-sample/post-migration/sourceData/config_-e48059402bd4.json] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

```
private InputStream streamHelper(String resourcePath) {
    DefaultResourceLoader resourceLoader = new DefaultResourceLoader();
    Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource(resourcePath);
    return resource.getInputStream();
}
```

I print the file name on console, when I click that link it can direct me to the file which means the path is good, why I got this error? How to fix that.

Comment: can you share the link that you are clicking? Does using this snippet work -             private InputStream streamHelper(String resourcePath) {
    return new FileInputStream(resourcePath);
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DefaultResourceLoader` is a Spring class.  According to [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/DefaultResourceLoader.html), the `DefaultResourceLoader`

> Will return a UrlResource if the location value is a URL, and a ClassPathResource if it is a non-URL path or a "classpath:" pseudo-URL.

By default, Spring looks for all your resources in a [folder called resources](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources#spring-boot).

> By default, this handler serves static content from any of the /static, /public, /resources, and /META-INF/resources directories that are on the classpath. Since src/main/resources is typically on the classpath by default, we can place any of these directories there.

Move your json into a folder called resources, make sure that folder is on your classpath, and then call the `streamHelper` as follows:

```java
streamHelper("classpath:config_-e48059402bd4.json")
```

Comment: Hi, is there a way no need to move json file to resources folder? Cuz it's require to generated to above folder

Comment: Yes, this is possible via a [custom directory](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources#2-custom-directories).  In your Spring configuration, set the `spring.web.resources.static-locations=classpath:/sourceData/`

Comment: The benefit of using the classpath location is that it makes your code portable, whereas `/Users/my/....` is not portable.  If this is not important to you then you can simple use `java.io.FileInputStream​("/Users/my/IdeaProjects/ru....")`